# How can I get the LLVM IR dump from XLA in TensorFlow?

Tags: compilation, tensorflow

I am trying to get the LLVM IR generated by the XLA Compiler in TensorFlow. I know that the entire LLVM Context is contained in the `llvm_module` object. This is then converted to a string with the utility function `llvm_ir::DumpModuleToString(*llvm_module)` function in the `Compile()` function in the file: `//tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu.cpu_compiler.cc`.

But I have been trying to log it using `VLOG(2)` from `tensorflow/core/logging.h`. No logs are shown. However, the remaining VLOG(2) statements from other files are logged in my Python run.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
2017-03-10 22:36:43.226843: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-03-10 22:36:43.227931: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0x2821510 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2017-03-10 22:36:43.227951: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Comment: I think there are a couple of things missing here: (1) XLA currently doesn't (to the best of my knowledge) handle strings, so it's unlikely that this program would be compiled by XLA, and (2) I think you have to explicitly specify an XLA device or `jit_scope()` to make XLA compile a subgraph. The docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit) have more information.

Comment: I tried running it on the ```mnist_softmax``` example given on the page as well. To no avail. I just rebuilt tensorflow from source and tried again. I think XLA is not being invoked. chrome://tracing is not showing an XLA module.

Comment: Update: I was running on a Arch Linux machine. Now running inside docker. XLA is invoked for sure. (Can see the ```_XlaCompiledKernel=true``` flags and stuff ). But still no IR dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FYI I can't leave comments, since I just joined and apparently don't have a reputation yet.]

First off, make sure to read this, including the starred blue boxes.  In particular note that turning on XLA for your whole session only performs JIT for GPU, and not CPU at the moment.
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit

Now let's assume you've got everything set up correctly.  The program in your example won't use XLA to compile for 2 reasons:

1. As @mrry has noted, XLA doesn't handle strings.
2. Even if you replaced the string with a number, you still wouldn't see any IR dump, because it's just a single constant, and XLA will have constant-folded it away.

In the comments you mentioned running on mnist_softmax, presumably following the instructions on the link above.  If you're indeed compiling and running on CPU, the only remaining issue is using VLOG(2).  VLOG is only enabled if you set command-line flags to turn it on.

**So try replacing your VLOG(2) with LOG(INFO), and you should see the IR dump in your logs.**

Comment: Worked like a charm :)
I was actually waiting for you to see this post, thank you! The response from the TensorFlow community is great!

Comment: Okay, IR dump got me confused again. There are *multiple* IR dumps in one execution. Is this because XLA is invoked on a subgraph of computation? if ( yes ) - then how can I get XLA to run on the whole graph?

Comment: [newbie here] @annanay25 Could you point me to a diff/patch where you were able to dump the IR ?