# How can obtain LLVM IR for the *entire* computation graph from TensorFlow in XLA?

Tags: compilation, tensorflow

I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724165/how-can-i-get-the-llvm-ir-dump-from-xla-in-tensorflow) yesterday about obtaining LLVM IR from TensorFlow graphs. I inserted `LOG(INFO) << llvm_ir::DumpModuleToString(*llvm_module)` in `CpuCompiler::Compile()` and obtained the LLVM IR. But this seems to be just a small fraction of the complete program.

I should also explain the bigger picture. Please go though [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8100) link which explains much more about what I want to implement in the XLA Compiler.

How can I get IR for the entire TensorFlow (XLA) computation graph? The videos in the Dev Summit indicate that XLA may not have the entire TensorFlow graphs because some of the TensorFlow ops (kernels) have not yet been implemented in XLA.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @AlexI. I dropped this approach altogether.